# Two Ethereum Node (connected to private net) on Single PC: Node data write error .Synchronisation failed

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, nodes, bootnodes

Is it possible to create 2 geth instance on single PC?
Both are connected the private blockchain?

When I connect a node to the private blockchain,it must sync with the blockchain by downloading all blocks upto latest one.Is this possible to do this on a 2nd node instance in same PC?

If not, what is the reason behind this?

I am getting the following error while I tried to run two instance.

**First Node** 
`geth --identity "TestNode1" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir <data-path-1> --port "30303" --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal,miner --networkid 987 console 2>> logfile_1`

**Second Node** 
`geth --identity "TestNode2" --rpcport "8545" --rpcaddr "xxx.xxx.xx.xx" --ipcdisable --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir <data-path-2> --port "30304" --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal,miner --networkid 987 console 2>> logfile_2`

**Error:**
`INFO [10-26|09:30:33.099] Block synchronisation started 
WARN [10-26|09:30:33.107] Node data write error err="state node 255a57…77b997 failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [10-26|09:30:33.107] Synchronisation failed, retrying err="state node 255a57…77b997 failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with separate `--datadir` and difference `--port` on the same PC

Comment: I have tried this, but the new node not downloading the blockchain.I have not seen any syncing information in log

Comment: can you provide more detail the cmd you start the two node on your question?

Comment: and by the way, you need to confirm that your node have peer then it can sync data from

Comment: Got errors:`Node data write error .sync failed retrying`

Comment: 2nd node instance: `geth --datadir < path> --rpcaddr 192.xxx.xx.xx --port "30305" --ipcdisable --networkid 987`

Comment: do you have any bootnode or enable rpc admin to see your node have any peers or not

Comment: and confirm that the write permission on the datadir path

Comment: I have checked the peer using the following command - `net.peerCount` and `admin.peers`.

Comment: what is the output of the two command?

Comment: Resolved :On both commands i have added --syncmode "fast". Now it is working , but at the end found few errors like - `Synchronisation failed, dropping peer.retrieved hash chain is invalid
Header broke chain ancestry` 
Any issue in Hash pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start another VM on your pc and download it there? This way you can keep things "cleaner".